# How to fix the width for each column in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I fix the width for each column in GridView. My GridView keeps extend along with data in the cell. I need it to skip to new line when it reach the right side of the cell. This is my code in .aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Emp_ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"
AllowPaging="True"  AllowSorting="True" Width="900px" HorizontalAlign="Center" >                        
           <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_ID" HeaderText="ID" 
        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Emp_ID"/>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Username" 
        HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Emp_Username" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Password" 
        HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Emp_Password" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Name" 
        HeaderText="ชื่อพนักงาน" SortExpression="Emp_Name" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Address" 
        HeaderText="ที่อยู่" SortExpression="Emp_Address" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Tel" 
        HeaderText="เบอร์โทรศัพท์" SortExpression="Emp_Tel" />
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="รูปพนักงาน" SortExpression="Emp_Picture">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Emp_Picture") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="70px" 
                                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Emp_Picture", "{0}") %>' Width="50px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="สถานะ" 
        SortExpression="Status" />
              <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Emp_ID" 
                                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AdminUpdate.aspx?Emp_ID={0}" Text="Edit" />
              <asp:TemplateField>
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelectAll" runat="server" 
                AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="ChkSelectAll_CheckedChanged"  />
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="Chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="Chk_CheckedChanged" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my design view:

[image: Imgur]

As you can see, the first 4 columns has no problem with that until column 5. It keeps extend cause all GridView extend out of the page

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Set-column-width-of-a-gridview-in-asp-net-with-code-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping is done based on words so that any single word is not broken in two lines.

So won't work for you if your data has long string without space.

The problem is that you can't insert spaces on your own because that may change the meaning of data.

While showing in grid `we show only that long string which can be accommodated in column and then add "..." (only if string is more than what is showing) and then add a tooltip to show the full string.`
That way the grid formatting is not compromised and if user wants he can hover his mouse and see the whole string.

hope this helps [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25980626/795683)

Comment: I just try and it's work now so I should add more space in the word. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: can you share a solution for this answer, i also have the same issue

Comment: @festusmutinda Please refer to this. Hope this helps you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/25980626/795683

Answer (score 3):

Set itemstyle width of every column.For example.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Address" 
    HeaderText="ที่อยู่" SortExpression="Emp_Address">
   <ItemStyle Width="200px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: It will expand vertically but not horizontally. Because you fixed the width.

Comment: Click on Up arrow above Zero.

Comment: I have just 12 rep. It need 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the property `RowStyle-Wrap` of the GridView to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ItemStyle-Width` to fix the column width ,but in case you enter characters which can not be enclosed in given width (As seen in your image)  ,column will expand as per the inputs so you can use `RowStyle-Wrap` property of gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdVwtrial" runat="server" RowStyle-Wrap="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

`RowStyle-Wrap==true` should work I guess. For more clarifications refer this:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1263769.aspx