# In a C# DataGridView with enabled AutoSize, can I lock the width of certain columns?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, datagridview

I would like to simply enable autosizing on my datagridview (or similar behavior). I want some columns to grow and fill all available space. However, I also have some columns that I want 100% fixed and to not grow at all, and I can't get this particular behavior.

Unfortunately, no matter what the fill rate is, I can't figure out how to lock the columns I don't want to change. So far, I have tried:

- Setting `FillWeight` to be extremely small on the columns I want locked. Unfortunately, this just causes the column to become sized too small off the bat, regardless of its initial width setting.
- Setting `Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False` only prevents the user from changing the size of that column. It still resizes automatically when I change the window size.

Does a solution exist? If I can't find one, I'll need to write up my own implementation, triggered using `DataGridView.Resize` I take it.

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990816/how-to-fix-the-width-for-each-column-in-gridview

Answer (score 0):

I see, `MinimumWidth` needs to be leveraged as part of the solution. `FillWeight = float.Epsilon, MinimumWidth = 50` seems to do the trick.